# Weblogic active thread have not increase when under high loading

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I am doing load test on a weblogic server.
When I fire a relative high loading to the server, the active thread count stop at 40-50 and never increase again.
When I fire a relative low loading to the server, the active thread count keeping increase util reach the limit.
I saw the oracle doc said the Throughput increase the active will incrase.
If there is a high loading, how the Throughput can increase. The active will never increase.

Comment: WebLogic uses workmanager to handle threads. Creation of new threads is based on runtime statistics on throughput and reponse times. You may need to increase your test load (more resquests per second) and your test duration to see Weblogic increasing the thread count.

Comment: I found that even I use the same load. The active thread also different. Sometime can reach 400 threads but sometime only 4-50 threads.

Comment: 400 threads is the default upper limit of execute threads created by WebLogic. In this situation you may investigate further and find where the contention is. Thread dumps will be very helpful in this situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I found that the cpu usage reach 80%. I suspect the cpu resource is not enough.

Comment: not sure. You should first see where your threads spend time. Fire multiple thread dumps to achieve this. The GC could be the root cause of you high cpu.